# Show that $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous if $f(x) = x^{1/k}$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I'm very confused right now and I want to apply the theorem that says " A mapping f of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$  for every open set $V$ in $Y$". However, I'm not sure how to implement this, I'm considering an open set $V=(a,b) \in [0,1] \subset Y$ and showing that $f^{-1}(V)$ is also open in $X$ hence $f$ is continuous. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean here that you are considering each of the maps $x\mapsto x^{1/k}$?  Clearly, $f(x)$ cannot be equal to $x^{1/k}$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: It states that "For any $k \in \mathbb N$ show that the function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=x^{1/k}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show $f$ is increasing. Then $f^{-1}((a, b)) = (a^k, b^k)$ which is open.

**Added Later:** It is enough to show that $f^{-1}((a, b))$ is open as $\mathcal{B} = \{(a, b) \mid 0 \leq a < b \leq 1\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a base for the topology on $[0, 1]$; that is, every open set in $[0, 1]$ can be written as a countable union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. Now, for any open $V \subseteq [0, 1]$, there are sets $I_n \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $V = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$, then $$f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\right) = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(I_n).$$ If you've shown that the preimage of every open interval is open, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is the countable union of open sets, and is therefore open. More generally, we have the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, $f : X \to Y$, and $\mathcal{B}$ be a base for the topology on $Y$. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every $V \in \mathcal{B}$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the way I'm reasoning is correct and would it actually prove that f is continuous?

Comment: I haven't learned about what a topology is so I'm not sure how to go about it the way you suggested.

Comment: You don't need to know what a topology is, you can just use the same argument; I used words like base and topology to summarise the proof and show it is actually a general one. For your purposes, all you need to do is show that every open set $V \subseteq [0, 1]$ can be written as the union of countably many intervals. Then the displayed line in my answer is the result you need.

Comment: Thank you, that made it much clearer! Since I'm struggling with the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, what would be a way to use that definition to show that this is continuous. It would help me a lot on how to see the definition being used. Thank you!